# Angular Ionic Capacitor iOS Keyboard is lagging

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I have some problem with my Capacitor Keyboard
I have next wrong flow:
1. Click on text area
2. My keaboard is up and my ion-footer is hidden (it's wrong)
3. After ~2 sec after keyboard is up, I can see my ion-footer

So, I just want normal behaviour, like in normal messengers (whataspp, facebook, instagramm etc)

```
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <form [formGroup]="form" class="form chat-input">
      <div class="input-wrapper row">
        <mat-form-field class="form__field">
          <mat-label>Сообщение</mat-label>
          <textarea (blur)="scrollToBottom()" (focusout)="scrollToBottom()" (keydown.enter)="sendMsg($event)"
            class="form-input" matInput formControlName="msg" type="text"></textarea>
        </mat-form-field>
        <div class="form__send-msg-btn" (click)="sendMsg($event)">
          <img src="assets/icon/send-message.svg" alt="send message" class="send-msg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

I have tried something like that

But it's work fine only while it in "will show" and after it's added +336px to height and my footer is gonna to header ao

```
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillShow', (info) => {
      // alert(`Keyboard height: ${info.keyboardHeight}`);
      this.keyboardHeight = info.keyboardHeight;
      this.isKeyboardVisible = true;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });

    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillHide', () => {
      this.keyboardHeight = 0;
      this.isKeyboardVisible = false;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
```